# How to create markers to my points in mapbox?

Tags: javascript, popup, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a dataset with different points on a map, stored on GitHub as a GeoJSON. I would like to assign popups to each point of that dataset, that would display some of its data attributes when clicked. I managed to copy some code from Mapbox tutorials but I don't know how to connect my points from the GeoJSON file with the markers.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .marker {
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/g/);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mapboxgl-popup {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamFua29tYWciLCJhIjoiY2ozNmNhMXQyMDQ4czMybzl6YTN2cDM0ciJ9.naD_i9iNOl_CEZ3WkY8Nvg';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
  center: [-96, 37.8],
  zoom: 3
});

map.addSource('worldcities_points', {
  type: 'geojson',
  data: 'https://github.com/jankomag/worldcitiespopchange/blob/master/readycities_geojson.geojson'
});

// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

  // create a HTML element for each feature
  var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://placekitten.com/g/' + marker.properties.iconSize.join('/') + '/)';
    el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
    el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';

    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.alert(marker.properties.message);
    });
  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
      .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
    .addTo(map);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.

Comment: Also, StackOverflow is specifically a site for programmers. If you want to learn to program, SO can help you. But you will need to stop saying "I'm not a developer" if you want to find assistance here.

Comment: @SteveBennett Ok, I am sorry about that. I have added some code now, but I'm not sure what I could do to make it work

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would recommend you not to share your access token. Others can use it and you will be billed. As you already have shared it, probably a good idea to disable it.

I have some comments to your code:

- You are adding a source. In order to show it on the map, you would have to create a layer for it and add it to the map.

> map.addSource('worldcities_points', {
>     type: 'geojson',
>     data: 'https://github.com/jankomag/worldcitiespopchange/blob/master/readycities_geojson.geojson'
>   });

--> To add it as a layer:

```js
        // Add a layer showing the places.
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'worldcities_points',
            'type': 'symbol',
            'source': 'worldcities_points',
            'layout': {
                'icon-image': '{icon}-15',
                'icon-allow-overlap': true
            }
        });
```

You can try to add the popups to the map after you have created them for your objects:

```js
        // Create a popup, but don't add it to the map yet.
        var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
            closeButton: false,
            closeOnClick: false
        });

        // Open the popup when mouse hover over the position of the object
        map.on('mouseenter', 'places', function(e) {
            // Change the cursor style as a UI indicator.
            map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';

            var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
            var description = e.features[0].properties.description;// assuming your source geoJSON  contains properties.descriptions

            // Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that multiple
            // copies of the feature are visible, the popup appears
            // over the copy being pointed to.
            while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
                coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
            }

            // Populate the popup and set its coordinates
            // based on the feature found.
            popup
                .setLngLat(coordinates)
                .setHTML(description)
                .addTo(map);
        });

        // remove the popup when the mouse leaves the position of the object
        map.on('mouseleave', 'places', function() {
            map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
            popup.remove();
        });
```

That should get you popups! Let me know if you have questions!

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I managed to get it done in a slightly different way